# Facebook SDK window.fbAsyncInit not firing on localhost? worked fine last week

Tags: facebook, sdk, initialization, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook SDK window.fbAsyncInit not firing on localhost? worked fine last week.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        console.log("hey");
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
          appId      : '***************', // App ID from the App Dashboard
          channelUrl : '//localhost/channel.html', // Channel File 
          status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
          cookie     : true, // set sessions 
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
        });
}
  // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
  // Note that the debug version is being actively developed and might 
  // contain some type checks that are overly strict. 
  // Please report such bugs using the bugs tool.
  (function(d, debug){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document, /*debug*/ true));
</script>
```

"hey" does not fire upon loading the page

additionally I noticed that when i comment out the channel url in the "Fb.init", but add the:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

within the header of the file, "hey" fires upon first loading the page, but not the upon subsequent tries

To be more explicit. This is what the error in my console reads:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js:9237
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed loads the SDK below FB.init().

```
(function(d, debug){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document, /*debug*/ false));`
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

and make sure you sets up `App Domains` in [App setting page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).

Comment: I have that part in my code, but it's just not relevant to window.fbAsyncInit firing. i'll add it to the code i posted above now just to be explicit though. Additionally, all the stuff in the App Domains is set up right. I mean, this whole process worked last week. I don't really understand what happened between now and then...

Comment: actually. i think u might be on to something. my part of the last function states "/*debug*/ true". after changing it to false, some functions in FB.init started working again and fb.AsyncInit fires every time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a bug in the rendering of the debug version of all.js - that is causing your code not to execute correctly. This will be resolved shortly.